# function to call parent category parent from child nested database

Tags: php, mysql

I have nested/tree database.
I need php function to call sub-parents to top parent when i call an id child. Below is example of my mysql structure database.

```
|id      |ket|
--------------
|01      |A  |
|0101    |B  |
|010101  |C  |
|010102  |D  |
|01010101|E  |
```

So, as an example if i call 01010101 it will return A-B-C-E
Any ideas how to make it happen.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By treating the id as the beginning of a pattern:

```
SELECT ket
FROM tbl
WHERE "01010101" LIKE CONCAT(id, '%')
```

BTW - horribly inefficient and no index use possible.